# Combine lists in forloop

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list of chromosomes `chromosomes <- c(1:2, "X", "Y")` that I am iterating over to generate random data `n` times for each `chromosome`.

I am doing this first by iterating over the `chromosomes` and generating the data using `generateData()` and then adding these to a list which I then combine into a data frame outside of the loop using `bp_data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, simByChrom))`:

```
chromosomes <- c(1:2, "X", "Y")
simByChrom <- list()

for (c in chromosomes){
  n <- sample(1:5,1)
  cat(paste("Simulating", n, "breakpoints on chromosome", c), "\n")
  bp_data <- generateData(c, n)
  simByChrom[[c]] <- bp_data
}

bp_data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, simByChrom))
rownames(bp_data) <- NULL
```

---

```
# generate dummy data
generateData <- function(c, n){
  df <- data.frame(chrom = rep(c, n),
                    pos= sample(1:10000, n))
  return(df)
}
```

---

```
  chrom  pos
1     1 7545
2     2 5798
3     2 3863
4     3 4036
5     3 9347
6     3 4749
```

I would like to iterate over this multiple times and record the iteration number in `bp_data$iteration`, to produce a data frame that looks like this:

```
chrom  pos  iteration
     1 7215 1
     1 4606 1
     2 8282 1
     2 3501 1
     2 4350 1
     2 6044 1
     X 2467 1
     Y 2816 1
     Y 8848 1
     Y 2304 1
     Y 4235 1
     1 3760 2
     1 8205 2
     1 4735 2
     2 3061 2
     X   56 2
     X 1722 2
     X 2430 2
     X 6749 2
     X 2081 2
     Y 9646 2
```

However, I'm unsure how to do this. I've tried:

```
iterations <- 2
for (i in (1:iterations)){
  cat("Running iteration", i, "\n")
  simByChrom <- list()

  for (c in chromosomes){
    n <- sample(1:5,1)
    cat(paste("Simulating", n, "breakpoints on chromosome", c), "\n")
    bp_data <- generateData(c, n)
    bp_data$iteration <- i
    simByChrom[[c]] <- bp_data

    # or 
    # simByChrom[[c]][[i]] <- bp_data

    # or 
    # simByChrom[[c]] <- bp_data
    # simByChrom[[c]]$iteration <- i
  }

  bp_data <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, simByChrom))
  rownames(bp_data) <- NULL

}
```

But this results in only the last iteration being recorded.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only seeing the last iteration in your result is because `bp_data` is being over-written each time through the for loop.  You need to make sure you save each iteration result separately and then combine them together at the end. 
 I believe just a few minor adjustments to what you already have will do the trick:

```
iterations <- 2

#create empty list to store each iteration result
bp_data <- list()

#run each iteration
for (i in 1:iterations){
  cat("Running iteration", i, "\n")
  simByChrom <- list()

  for (c in chromosomes){
    n <- sample(1:5,1)
    cat(paste("Simulating", n, "breakpoints on chromosome", c), "\n")
    aa <- generateData(c, n)
    aa$iteration <- i
    simByChrom[[c]] <- aa
  }

  result <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, simByChrom))
  rownames(result) <- NULL
  bp_data[[i]] <- result
}

#combine each iteration into one data frame
final <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, bp_data))
```